# Send data to server: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, exception, post, message

I'm creating a class for my Android application that send data to my server but i'm experiencing the above error.
What could be the problem?
Here all the code that i write in the class.

```
public class MyForm extends Activity {

    EditText username;
    Button sendButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registrazione);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

public void send(View v) {
    String user = username.getText().toString();

    if(user.length() > 0) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("hxxp://www.mysite.com/form.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", user));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               httpclient.execute(httppost);
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Here is my LogCat:

```
05-17 19:57:39.153: D/OpenGLRenderer(6056): Enabling debug mode 0
05-17 19:57:56.628: D/AndroidRuntime(6056): Shutting down VM
05-17 19:57:56.628: W/dalvikvm(6056): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418647c0)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3635)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     ... 11 more
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     at com.example.bpem.Registrazione.send(Registrazione.java:71)
05-17 19:57:56.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6056):     ... 14 more
05-17 19:58:01.368: I/Process(6056): Sending signal. PID: 6056 SIG: 9
05-17 19:58:01.748: D/libEGL(6182): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-17 19:58:01.748: D/libEGL(6182): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-17 19:58:01.753: D/libEGL(6182): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-17 19:58:01.758: E/(6182): Device driver API match
05-17 19:58:01.758: E/(6182): Device driver API version: 17
05-17 19:58:01.758: E/(6182): User space API version: 17 
05-17 19:58:01.758: E/(6182): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013 
05-17 19:58:01.773: D/OpenGLRenderer(6182): Enabling debug mode 0
05-17 19:59:02.228: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6182): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-17 20:00:45.038: D/AndroidRuntime(6182): Shutting down VM
05-17 20:00:45.038: W/dalvikvm(6182): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418647c0)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3635)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     ... 11 more
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     at com.example.bpem.Registrazione.send(Registrazione.java:71)
05-17 20:00:45.048: E/AndroidRuntime(6182):     ... 14 more
05-17 20:00:46.228: I/Process(6182): Sending signal. PID: 6182 SIG: 9
05-17 20:00:46.628: D/libEGL(6386): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-17 20:00:46.628: D/libEGL(6386): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-17 20:00:46.633: D/libEGL(6386): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-17 20:00:46.643: E/(6386): Device driver API match
05-17 20:00:46.643: E/(6386): Device driver API version: 17
05-17 20:00:46.643: E/(6386): User space API version: 17 
05-17 20:00:46.643: E/(6386): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013 
05-17 20:00:46.658: D/OpenGLRenderer(6386): Enabling debug mode 0
05-17 20:01:46.898: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6386): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-17 20:09:55.438: D/libEGL(6658): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-17 20:09:55.438: D/libEGL(6658): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-17 20:09:55.448: D/libEGL(6658): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-17 20:09:55.453: E/(6658): Device driver API match
05-17 20:09:55.453: E/(6658): Device driver API version: 17
05-17 20:09:55.453: E/(6658): User space API version: 17 
05-17 20:09:55.453: E/(6658): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013 
05-17 20:09:55.478: D/OpenGLRenderer(6658): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: please post your logcat...

Comment: Done, sorry i forgot to do it before...

Comment: Did you check my answer @smartmouse???

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it helped you..Please give me an upvote too..please..@smartmouse

Comment: Done... i did not do it before because it disapperead... now i can see it again...